# How to extract date from the string format timestamp?

Tags: python

I want to extract the date (eg.`2018-07-16`) from strings (eg. `2018-07-16 10:17:53.460035`).

The strings have two formats: `"2018-07-16 10:17:53.460035"` and `"2018-05-20 14:37:21"`.

When I use `strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")` to convert the strings before extracting the date, it pops this error:

```
ValueError: time data '2018-05-20 14:37:21' does not match format
%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

How can I convert both time formats to DateTime type and extract date from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `to_datetime` from pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
a = "2018-07-16 10:17:53.460035"
b = "2018-05-20 14:37:21"
print(pd.to_datetime(a).date())
print(pd.to_datetime(b).date())
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answers! I have more than 1000 strings, how can I change them automatically instead of one-by-one by hand?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(your_list)).dt.date`. Don't forget to accept as correct answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the `.%f` at the end for the first format, that is what is causing the format error.

```
t = "2018-05-20 14:37:21"

strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

You need to create a second format for the other time string:

```
t = "2018-07-16 10:17:53.460035"

strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Edit: Here is another example which excepts both

```
time_stamps = ["2018-05-20 14:37:21", "2018-07-16 10:17:53.460035"]

for stamp in time_stamps:

    fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

    try:

        time = datetime.datetime.strptime(stamp, fmt+".%f")

    except ValueError:

        time = datetime.datetime.strptime(stamp, fmt)

        print(time)
```

Comment: If you are suggesting `datetime.strptime()` from datetime module, it won't work for format "2018-07-16 10:17:53.460035" without the .%f.

Comment: deciding which format to use for which string, for a large list of string that needs conversion is going to be difficult. You may put some condition on the string length. But is is too complex. Python zen says **Simple is better than Complex**